# Is there a way around Apple's UITextField Emoji bug?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit, ios10, emoji

So, Apple has a bug right now where if you type an Emoji into a UITextField, it will shift the text down. In fact, if you type enough emojis and then backspace, it'll shift the text even further down from where it was supposed to be. I confirmed this by trying UITextFields in Twitter, Snapchat and other apps.

[Here is a video of my app displaying the bug.](https://streamable.com/gg6h)

Answer (score 3):

Use this: `textField.clipsToBounds = false`

It prevents the `textField` to move when editing. Even when you try to edit it again.

(Tested on iPhone 6, iOS 10.0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think their would be a way around this, as it just seems that the emoji is changing the margin of the text inside of the UITextField.